# How do I get youtube broadcasts to autostart when I livestream?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I have been working on a streaming integration with the youtube live api. I am facing issues with the following two scenarios:

1. A broadcast created/binded to an inactive livestream with `contentDetails.enableAutoStart: true` and `contentDetails.monitorStream.enableAutoStart: false` does not automatically start when I begin streaming.
2. A broadcast created/binded to an active livestream with the same configuration above does not automatically start.

I have successfully wired in manual transitioning (with and without a monitor stream/testing phase). However, I cannot seem to reliably get the broadcasts to autostart in the aforementioned situations.